# How to stop a running method with another method?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, super

So this is my university assignment which I got pretty much everything done. It is supposed to use method overriding, which I have to do from my class SafeRidingMower (will insert code after explanation) which extends from my professor's class (which I CANNOT change a single thing) RidingMower.

RidingMower Class:

```
    import java.util.*;

/**
 * The riding mower class developed by the engineering department. Contains all the functionality needed
 * for a working riding mower.
 *
 */
public class RidingMower {

    private boolean rider_in_seat = false;

    private boolean is_engine_on = false;

    private boolean is_mower_enabled = false;

    private Random rn = new Random();

    /**
     * Constructor for Riding Mower which automatically launches the main menu.
     */
    public RidingMower()
    {
        mainMenu();
    }

    /** Starts the engine of the riding mower (ignition start) */
    public void start_engine()
    {
        System.out.println("<<< Starting riding mower >>>");

        is_engine_on = true;
    }

    /** Method that randomly seats and unseats a driver */
    private void sit_rider()
    {

        int random = rn.nextInt(5);

        if ( random<=1 )
             rider_in_seat = true;
        else rider_in_seat = false;       

        System.out.print("\t=>Seated? " + rider_in_seat + "\n");
    }

    /** Seat sensor. Returns true if there is a driver seated on the mower or false
     * if no driver is sitting on the mower.
     * @return 
     */
    public boolean check_seat_sensor()
    {   
        return rider_in_seat;
    }

    /** Method that engages the mower blades and begins mowing if the ignition is turned on */
    public void mow()
    {
        start_mowing();
    }

    /** Primary method that handles the mowing. Checks to see if the ignition is on then the 
      mowing starts otherwise the cutting blades are lowered and ready to mow upon engine start
      */
    private void start_mowing()
    {

        is_mower_enabled = true;

        System.out.println("Mower blade ready to mow");

        if ( !is_engine_on ) return;

        int i=1;

        while (true)
        {
            mowing(i++);

        }
    }

    /** Mower fully functioning here and blades are spinning. Simulates a rider being thrown off 
     the mower at step 50,000 */
    private void mowing(int i)
    {
        System.out.println( "Mowing..." + i);

        if ( i>50000 ) rider_in_seat = false;

        if ( rider_in_seat == false )
            System.out.println("\tOMG Mower is moving without a driver?!");

        mowing_hook();
    }

    /** Hook/Stub function called while the mower is mowing. Other departments divisions can override */
    public void mowing_hook()
    {

    }

    /** Turns off the ignition. Stops the mower if running. */
    public void stop_mower()
    {
        System.out.println("Stopping the mower.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /** Main menu of the mower simulation. Asks user to check/seat a driver, start the mower, 
     * begn mowing the lawn, or exiting the simulation. Method is private and can not be 
     * overriden.
     */
    private void mainMenu()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
        int option;

        do
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("1. Is driver seated? (" + rider_in_seat +")" );
            System.out.println("2. Start mower");
            System.out.println("3. Mow the lawn");
            System.out.println("4. Stop mower (if running) and Exit.");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("CHOOSE 1-4");

            option = sc.nextInt();

            switch ( option )
            {        
                case 1: sit_rider();
                        break;

                case 2: start_engine();
                        if ( is_mower_enabled ) mow();
                        break;

                case 3: mow();
                        break;

                case 4: stop_mower();
                        break;
            }

        } while ( true ); // Infinite loop here. Select option #4 to exit the program.
    }
}
```

SafeRidingMower Class:

```
public class SafeRidingMower extends RidingMower 
{

    @Override
    public void start_engine() {
        if (check_seat_sensor() == true)
            super.start_engine();
        else
            System.out.println("Seat sensor does not detect a driver."
                    + "Engine will not start.");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean check_seat_sensor() {
        return super.check_seat_sensor();
    }

    @Override
    public void mow() {
        if (check_seat_sensor() == true)
            super.mow();
        else if (check_seat_sensor() == false)
            System.out.println("Seat sensor does not detect a driver."
                    + " Mower will not start.");
        else
            System.out.println("Engine is not on. Cannot start mowing.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mowing_hook() {

    }
}
```

And the Driver, which I assume it's not relevant for the specific issue I'm having, but here it is anyway.

```
public class TheLawnMowerManDriver {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    RidingMower mower = new SafeRidingMower();

}
```

}

What I need to do: in the RidingMower class, there is the method mowing() which I cannot override, but I can override the method mowing_hook() which is called at the end of the method mowing(). What I'm supposed to do is to stop the lawnmower from running when the variable i = 50000, but I have no idea how to do so. I tried using the super keyword with the variable, but it didn't work (I don't know if it was supposed to work or not, I was only introduced to the super keyword a few classes ago).

Does anyone know a way that I can stop the lawnmower/stop the variable i from counting from overriding the mowing_hook() method?

Comment: Doesn't make sense, `mowing_hook` has no visibility of `i`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Exactly, but I have to figure out some way to make it the lawnmower stop after 50000. The code provided on RidingMower is my professor's and I did not change a single thing, as he requested, so I don't understand either.

Comment: I assume you are expected to throw an exception from your `mowing_hook` override, when `check_seat_sensor()` returns false.  There is no other way to halt the infinite loop in start_mowing.  (Also, someone needs to smack your professor and tell him/her that Java is not C and it is not acceptable to write C-like identifiers in Java programs.)

Comment: ... throw an exception or call `stop_mower()`. This looks to be a pretty terrible course, though.

Comment: There is no compulsion that `sit_rider` is ever called, so it looks like `check_seat_sensor() returns false` but `i` could be less than 5000

Comment: @VGR I thought about doing something with check_seat_sensor() but could not figure out what. Also, we just started learning about exceptions so I don't think he expects us to use it on this assignment (given about a week or so ago), even if he did I don't know yet how to use it.

Comment: @Thilo how so (about it being a pretty terrible course)? I had no contact with programming before starting university so I don't have a sense on what's good teaching on it and what is not lol

Comment: The start_mowing method contains `while (true) { mowing(i++); }`.  There is no way to stop that loop, other than throwing an exception or calling System.exit.

Comment: As was said above, `mowing_hook` cannot really do anything useful. It does not see `i`, it does not return a flag or anything. My guess is they expect you to call `check_seat_sensor` and then `stop_mower()` (C-style naming is another bad smell, as is calling `System.exit()`), but that does not really check the step count either, just if the driver is still in the seat. This whole setup is just bad. (The course might still be good, but this test is not)

Comment: I don't know what you guys mean when you say C-Style naming is bad (again, new at programming, never touched anything other than java) lol, but I guess I'll just hand in my assignment like this since I don't think he will deduct a lot of marks, then I'll ask him for a solution to the problem and I'll post it here, since I'm very confused and curious as well

Comment: @Bela, I thought a lot about this and my conclusion is that problably you missunderstood the assignment. I believe that the rule is not `i == 50000` but is `i > 50000` and in the method `mowing_hook()` you should add this line of code `if (!rider_in_seat) stop_mower();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem.

As I said, I believe that or you missunderstood the problem or your professor is tricking you.

Anyway, it is possible to stop the execution if we watch the `mowing()` method execution `indirectly`.

**The idea is to wrapper the System.out and record the last string that was printed. So, in `mowing_hook()` we can see watch was printed and stop when necessary.**

You can find a working example here: jdoodle.com/a/12KZ

In summary:

Add this class to you code

```
class SystemOutWrapper extends PrintStream{
    String lastLine;

    public SystemOutWrapper(OutputStream out){
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void println (String str){
        this.lastLine = str;
        super.println(str);
    }

    public String getLastLine(){
        return lastLine;
    }
}
```

And override the method this way

```
@Override
public void mowing_hook() {

    if (! (System.out instanceof SystemOutWrapper)){
        System.setOut(new SystemOutWrapper(System.out));
    }

    //I used 100 as the online editor limitation. But you should change to 50000
    if ("Mowing...100".equals( ((SystemOutWrapper) System.out).getLastLine())){
        System.out.println("Limite reached! Should stop now!");
        stop_mower();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigadaaaa! I figured it out yesterday too, for some reason I thought stop_mower() was private so I apologize for that. Still, I found no way to stop the mower before the driver gets thrown off... well, at least I still got 100% on the it!

Answer (score 0):

Once:
    1. `i` is a local variable of the method `mowing()` and;
    2. The method `mowing()` dont pass the value of `i` to the method `mowing_hook()`

**So, it is impossible to read the value of `i` in the method `mowing_hook()`.**

I have two hipotesis:
    1. Your professor is tricking with you
    2. You missunderstand the assignment

I will give some alterantives:

1. Change the signature of the method `mowing_hook()`

   ```
   /** Mower fully functioning here and blades are spinning. Simulates a rider being thrown off the mower at step 50,000 */
   private void mowing(int i)
   {
       System.out.println( "Mowing..." + i);

       if ( i>50000 ) rider_in_seat = false;

       if ( rider_in_seat == false )
           System.out.println("\tOMG Mower is moving without a driver?!");

       mowing_hook(i);
       }

       public void mowing_hook(int i)
       {

       }
   }
   ```

   And override this way

   ```
   @Override
   public void mowing_hook(int i) {
       if (i == 50000) stop_mower();
   }
   ```
2. Or use the instance variable `rider_in_seat`

   ```
   @Override
   public void mowing_hook(int i) {
       if (!rider_in_seat) stop_mower(); 
   }
   ```

   But realize that `rider_in_seat` will be set to false only when `i > 50000` because of the line `if ( i>50000 ) rider_in_seat = false;`

Comment: *rider_in_seat will be set to false only...* **or** if option 1 is never called

Comment: @ScaryWombat, yes. But I am saying in the context of `mowing_hook` that is invoked inside `mowing`.

Comment: Maybe I am reading the code wrong, but `rider_in_seat ` is set via a call to random when option 1 is called.  This option is optional and may never even be called.  So, `i` could have a value of `one` **and** `rider_in_seat` could be `false`

Comment: @ScaryWombat, the method `mow()` was overriden in the subclass SafeRidingMower and It will not start if `rider_in_seat` was false. It seams that this flag check is part of her job in exercise.